# Add Alt text on Media Images while uploading - Umbraco

Tags: image, umbraco, media

I am using Umbraco 7.5.3 and I want to add an alt text to media images while uploading or while selecting (On clicking submit) them using media picker. Is this possible?

I have added a property to Image Media Type. This way it is available for all the images I have in the CMS.

But another question I am getting stucked with. Is it good or bad to change inbuilt Umbraco data types?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this, I have added an alternative text property to the media Image type. (Settings -> Media Types -> Image).

You can see the below image.

[image: AlternativeText]

Comment: That is how you can add alt text from the Media Library, but not from the standard media picker.

Comment: It isn't from the standard media picker but I think this makes more sense - 
 keeping the alt text associated to the image.

Answer (score 3):

It's not currently possible to add ALT text to images whilst uploading / selecting images using the standard media picker.

To fulfil this functionality you would need to extend the data type.

Extending existing datatypes & creating new data types is encouraged, Umbraco is an open source project so you could even create a pull request on GitHub.

I would be very interested as this is a feature that I also would like to see in core.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I have added an alternative text property on the Media Image Type and this served as a solution.